# Firebase Realtime Database Rule Access parent variable from child

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

How can I access variable `$cliente`?
The `auth.token.place == $cliente` comparison fails.

`auth.token.place` is fine I compare with a constant (`auth.token.place == 23`) and it works. But `$cliente` compared with the same constant fails (`$cliente == 23`).

I have this rule below:

```json
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    "clientes" : {      
      "$cliente" : {
        "tvs" : {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": false,
        },    
        "chats" : 
        {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": "auth !== null && auth.token.place == $cliente"
        }
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

```
firebase.database().ref('clientes/'+id+'/chats/'+dest).set({
  from: MY_ID,
  to: msg_to,
  message : " ",
  date: Date.now()
});
```

Structure example:

```
clientes
    2
      tvs
        ...
      chats      
        128_239
         { from: "239"
           message:"fngdkfngd dkfjfds"
           to:128,
           date: 543657654654
         }
```

I just want to give access to users that belongs from the same `$cliente`.

I am getting PERMISSION DENIED.

Comment: The syntax of your `$cliente` reference looks correct to me at first glance, to most like the problem is in the values you're comparing.  Can you edit your question to show the minimal code that produce the problem against these rules, **and** prove in that code how it meets the conditions of the rules (i.e. log the auth token and show the path you write)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edited. is that what you asked?

Comment: Partially. Please also prove that the request meets the conditions of the rules. For example you could `console.log` the auth token and `id` and show the updated code and its output, so that we can all see that `id` matches the value of the `place` claim in your token.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if I put just the rule ".write": "auth !== null" it works. So I am using the right ids

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @Guilherme. This type of debugging approach is in general the best way to either find the problem yourself, or end up with the info we need in a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

Actually auth.token.place is a number not a String and @cliente is a String.

So I need to convert to compare. That is how I did.

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    "clientes" : {      
      "$cliente" : {
        "tvs" : {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": false,
        },    
        "chats" : 
        {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": "auth !== null && (''+auth.token.place) == $cliente"
        }
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Good to hear you figured out the problem and got it working @Guilherme. This type of debugging approach is in general the best way to either find the problem yourself, or end up with the info we need in a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.